Why in Spring @Autowired annotation on a constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor?
I am in the beginning of study of Spring framework and I read this in Spring official docs.
"As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which one to use."
I wander what happen under the hood in Spring framework to make @Autowired annotation unnecessary if it has just one constructor and why? Also why that not happen in case of multiple constructor?

Through a bean-defining annotation, spring already knows that an instance of this class should be created (and registered as a bean). If there is only one constructor, it is obvious how to construct said object. With multiple constructors, it is not obvious, thus we need to mark the constructor to use with @Autowired.

This simplification is based on the principle that when a class has only one constructor, it is inherently clear to the Spring container which constructor to use for dependency injection. Therefore, marking this constructor with @Autowired becomes redundant since there is no ambiguity about which constructor to use.
This change was made to reduce boilerplate code and make the configuration more straightforward. It allows developers to focus on the business logic of their application without worrying about the explicit annotation of constructors for dependency injection, especially in cases where there is only one constructor available.
However, it's important to note that if a class has multiple constructors, at least one of them must be annotated with @Autowired to instruct the Spring container which constructor to use for autowiring. This requirement ensures that the container knows exactly which constructor to invoke when creating an instance of the bean.
This feature simplifies the development process by reducing the need for explicit annotations in certain scenarios, making the code cleaner and easier to read.
